# Custom UISlider does not reach edge

Tags: ios, uikit

So I made a custom UISlider, but the thumb will not reach the end points of the track. Is there a way to fix this?

[image: set to max]

[image: set to min]

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self setThumbImage:         [UIImage imageNamed:@"Thumb.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setMinimumTrackImage:  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Min.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setMaximumTrackImage:  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Max.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 5)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: The frame of the thumb image actually reaches the end points of the track. (upper left and right corners). The problem is that it doesn't visually look like it, due to the shape of the thumb image. I guess you were expecting this to be fixed by using `resizableImageWithCapInsets`.

Comment: Hey! Did you solve it?